# Processing: assign a value to each object in an array?

Tags: arrays, object, variable-assignment

Sorry this is probably a dumb question. I'm kinda new to coding and I'm using Processing, which is based off Java.

I have an array of 5 rectangle objects in my main program

```
 for (int i = 0; i < portals.length; i++)
  {
    portals[i] = new Portals();
  }
```

when displayed, I call this method from my Portals class

```
void display()
  {
    rectMode(CENTER);
    rect(xLoc, yLoc, rad, 30);
  }
```

the xLoc and yLoc are determined randomly. How would you go about assigning a number (like an identity) to each object in the array so that I can refer to that specific rectangles's location and where would I put it in my code?

Comment: Maybe show some more code (like your Portals class) and explain exactly what you wish to accomplish

Comment: Doesn't really work like that. Take a look at my answer, see if that helps. If you want a solution using a `Map`, I can show you, but if you're still beginning, I wouldn't dig into it just yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a filed in the class that makes it identifiable. Like:

```
public class Portals {
    int xLoc;
    int yLoc;
    String name;

    ...

    public Portals(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

Then you can try to access by name in array

```
for (int i = 0; i < portals.length; i++)
{
    portals[i] = new Portals("Name");
}

for (Portals p : portals){
    if ("Name".equals(p.getname()) {
        // do somthing
    }
}
```

---

Or you can use a `Map`. But that may be more advanced than your knowledge, so I won't give code. But that's another suggestion.

**Edit: with Map**

```
Map<String, Portals> map = new HashMap<String, Portals>();

            Key               Value
map.put("nameForPortal", new Portals());
map.put("anotherNameForPortal", new Portals());

// To access the portal, you can get by the key 

Portals p = map.get("nameForPortal");
```